# How to edit htaccess file without modifying back with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am editing htaccess file but after refreshing the website, it will modify back by wordpress.
here is my changes:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# دستورالعمل‌های (خطوط) بین BEGIN WordPress و END WordPress
# به طور پویا تولید شده‌اند، و فقط باید به وسیلهٔ صافی‌های وردرپرس ویرایش شوند.
# هر تغییری در دستورالعمل‌های بین این نشان‌گرها بازنویشی خواهند شد.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/.*/$ attributel/index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-v(\d+)-.*/$ attributel/index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^c-(.*)/$ attributel/index\.php?cat=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And I want to add these lines of codes:

```
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
 RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: If you need to add custom lines, you need to add them _outside_ of the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comments. The lines between those will be overwritten by WP, when the permalink settings get updated.

Comment: I have added outside those tags but still overwritten by WP.